# Wicket form would not load/render

Tags: html, forms, wicket

So I have a Wicket Panel that would not be rendered or loaded in our live server but it sure does in our development server.

I have checked that the html file is there, and also that the java file is loaded, the constructor and initialize method are called and executed (I see it in the server logs, also there is no exception or error messages), but then the html file is not shown.

My Panel extends org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.GenericPanel. Is there any reason for which a panel would't be rendered/loaded?

That is the only Panel that wouldn't be loaded, and it is very strange because in our development server it does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok... I am SOOOOO stupid...

My development system is windows... so it is not case sensitive, our live server is linux, which is... so the java class name had one uppercase letter that was lowercase in the html file name... Genius!

Comment: A tip if you use Eclipse, there is a plugin to generate html and java files at the same time: [qwickie](https://code.google.com/p/qwickie/). It also offers some other good wicket dev stuff :)